# How to stream PDFs from outside the web root to google's docs reader

Tags: php, pdf, stream, google-docs

Im trying to workout if i can stream PDF files from behind the web root via an image/pdf viewer.  Google's documentation says to embed a PDF in an HTML page you just use html and include an embed and point to the file.

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=YourDocumentUrlHere
```

However for the purposes of security I am using a document/image script that streams the file to the browser and therefore the filepath remains hidden from the view of the user and unable to be accessed by google documents.

The output sent by the document image script is in the form

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile("/home/******/*****/images/enquiries/23251/23251-1.pdf");
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

JUST IN CASE ANYONE WAS WONDERING... i added this to the image server script (imageserve.php)

```
if ($type = "application/pdf") {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
} else
```

and then on the page where i wanted to display the pdf i added

```
$temp = "home/..../..../development/imageserve.php?filename=xxxxxx";
<embed style="width:1200px; height:730px;" name="plugin" src="$temp" type="application/pdf">
```